# Durandal - pass parameter to define function on require

Tags: javascript, require, durandal

I have a durandal project.
In my project, I have parent-view and son-view.

Parent call son by require.
I nedd the son to get any param from parent, but I cannot use paasing params on router or constructor, becouse I don't navigate to the son, I only put it in the parent view, and it is singleton- so it not have a constractor.

see a sample:

```
 define(function(require){
      require('myFolder/son/son');
      var parentVM = {};
      return parentVM;
 });


 define(function(require){    
      var sonVM= {
           activate:function(myParam){
              //myCode, how can I get here my param from parent view?
           }
      };
      return sonVM;
 });
```

Comment: Why don't you use widgets? By the description looks like a better fit!
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Widget.html

Answer (score 0):

you could always publish the arguments: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe.html